# Override Core Data accessor

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to override my NSManagedObject accessor like this:

```
- (NSSet *)children {

    NSSet *children = nil;

    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"children"];
    children = [self primitiveChildren];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"children"];

   //if no children, let's look in our db to see if any children
   //belong to me (parent object), and if they do, let's assign the
   //children to myself (parent)
    if(!children.count) {

         NSFetchRequest *request = [ChildMO fetchRequestForManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
         request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"predicate IN %@", @[self.id]];

         children = [NSSet setWithArray:[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]];

         [self willChangeValueForKey:@"children"];
         [self setPrimitiveChildren:children];
         [self didChangeValueForKey:@"children"];
    }

    return children;
}
```

However, when I call 'willChangeValueForKey' just before assigning the children NSSet to my ManagedObject, the children getter seems to be called again and I enter into an infinite loop condition.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do not execute fetches in NSManagedObject subclasses. This is totally against how one should use Core Data. Just don't do it please. Your code is broken on so many levels. Please read the basic Core Data documentation again.

Comment: What @ChristianKienle said;  getters should be dead simple (preferably not overridden at all).  Your controller layer should generally be the one that determines when data should be fetched.   That code is going to lead to a world of pain.